# Tkinter button does not appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button, position

I am trying to build a small GUI for my D&D character but my second attack button does not appear.

Tried to make it read as easy as possible. Its my second try on programming, I find the Tkinter really difficult to work with :(

Written in Python 3:

[image]

```
# Tkinter_buildframe #

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack( side = TOP )
frame.pack()
root.geometry("300x200")


# This is the charicter stats #
w = Label(root, text="""
charisma modifier = 4
spellcast attack_bonus = 7
""", font="12")
w.pack()


# Quit_button #
button = tk.Button(frame,
                   text="QUIT",
                   fg="red",
                   command=quit)
button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

# Attack1 eldritch_blast_with_hex #

slogan = tk.Button(frame,
                   text="Eldritch Blast with Hex",
                   command=eldritch_blast_with_hex)
slogan.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


root.mainloop()
def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Eldritch Blast with Hex")
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=NORM_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()

# Attack2 eldritch_blast_without_hex#

slogan = tk.Button(frame,
                   text="Eldritch Blast without Hex",
                   command=eldritch_blast_without_hex)
slogan.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


root.mainloop()
def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Eldritch Blast without Hex")
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=NORM_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
```

Comment: You have some repeated code at the end, please make sure to prove the right code. Also which button is not appearing in the GUI

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the following and only kept on (out of 2) then it worked. 

root.mainloop()
def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Eldritch Blast without Hex")
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=NORM_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()

Comment: The Root.mainloop() at the end was dubbel in the code. Deleted on and kept one. Then it worked!

Comment: @CoolCloud done! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple `root.mainloop()` in the code, it just pauses the code from continuing the execution of rest of the code. So remove one of the `root.mainloop()` and place one at the end of the code.